# Getting my iPhone 6 to trust a computer after selecting Don't Trust

Tags: iphone, ios

I accidentally hit "Don't Trust" on my iPhone and now my MacBook won't unlock my phone. Is there a way to reverse this?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings → General → Reset → Reset Location & Privacy.

This will reset your trusted computers (along with all your other privacy settings), and next time you connect the device a computer, it will prompt you to trust it. The privacy settings this will reset are all the settings under Settings → Privacy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what else will be reset? "All your other privacy settings" = what specifically?

Comment: @owlswipe All your privacy settings is everything within Settings → Privacy. They will be reset to their default settings.